# How can I download an audio mp3 file and save it?

Tags: python, django, api

My View:

```
class UserSearchView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, link):
        url = config('BASE_URL')
        querystring = {"track_url": f'{link}'}
        headers = {
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": config('API_KEY'),
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": config('API_HOST')
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

        data = response.json()


        return JsonResponse(data)
```

My response :

```
{
    "url": "https://result.s3.amazonaws.com/2022-11-13/61566981.mp3"
}
```

Not sure how to proceed here, can anyone help ?----------------------

Answer (score 1):

You got this far, good.

```
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```

Now, just save the mp3.

```
        with open("music.mp3", "wb") as fout:
            fout.write(response.content)
```

EDIT

Here's a demo.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path

import requests


def download(url, out_file="audio.mp3"):
    out_file = Path(f"~/Desktop/{out_file}").expanduser()
    resp = requests.get(url)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    with open(out_file, "wb") as fout:
        fout.write(resp.content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    npr = "https://play.podtrac.com/npr-500005/edge1.pod.npr.org/anon.npr-mp3/npr"
    download(f"{npr}/newscasts/2022/11/13/20221113_newscasts_long_140735.mp3")
```

Comment: this saves me an mp3 correct, but still cannot play it for some reason

Comment: I don't understand your remark. I can't reproduce the behavior based on what you posted. The URL you mentioned 403's with a "forbidden" diagnostic. When I run the demo code above it plays great in VLC, QuickTime, Music, and Finder preview, on MacOS 12.6.1.

Comment: the url is an example, I didn't want to post the actual URL

Comment: The url I posted is a real example. It actually works, allowing SO readers to reproduce the described behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example